# Hedera Hashgraph Local Node AccountCreateTransaction Error

Tags: javascript, blockchain, tostring, private-key, hedera-hashgraph

I am currently trying to set up my local network by following the steps at https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/sdks/set-up-your-local-network.

I have the code:

```
const {
    Client,
    PrivateKey,
    Hbar,
    AccountId,
    AccountCreateTransaction,
} = require("@hashgraph/sdk");
require('dotenv').config();

const myAccountId = process.env.MY_ACCOUNT_ID;
const myPrivateKey = process.env.MY_PRIVATE_KEY;
const myPublicKey = process.env.MY_PUBLIC_KEY;


async function main() {


    console.log("account id is: " + process.env.MY_ACCOUNT_ID);

    const node = {"127.0.0.1:50211": new AccountId(3)};
    const client = Client.forNetwork(node).setMirrorNetwork("127.0.0.1:5600");

    //set the transsaction fee paying account
    client.setOperator(myAccountId, myPrivateKey);
    console.log('success');


    console.log(PrivateKey.fromString(myPublicKey));
    const newAccount = await new AccountCreateTransaction()
        
        .setKey(PrivateKey.fromString(myPublicKey))
        .setInitialBalance(new Hbar(1))
        .execute(client);

     //Get receipt
     const receipt = await newAccount.getReceipt(client);

     //Get the account ID
     const newAccountId = receipt.accountId;
     console.log(newAccountId);

}

void main();
```

The output that I consistently get represents failure at AccountCreateTransaction step:

```
/Users/{name}/Desktop/{org_name}/hello-hedera-js-sdk/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/Executable.cjs:679
    throw new Error(`max attempts of ${maxAttempts.toString()} was reached for request with last error being: ${persistentError != null ? persistentError.toString() : ""}`);
          ^

Error: max attempts of 10 was reached for request with last error being: GrpcServiceError: gRPC service failed with status: TIMEOUT
    at AccountCreateTransaction.execute (/Users/{name}/Desktop/{org_name}/hello-hedera-js-sdk/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/Executable.cjs:679:11)
    at async main (/Users/drew/Desktop/Greensmith/hello-hedera-js-sdk/localtx.js:31:24)
```

I have tried straight up copying and pasting the code found at the hedera site and even that returns the same error in my terminal. I have the hedera-local-node cluster running on my docker desktop and there were no issues starting it up. The console returns 'success' before the error indicating that `client.setOperator` function is working properly.

I have tried copying and pasting code directly from the site with given private_key and account_id. The same error returns. I have also tried `rm -rf node_modules` and then reinstalling with npm with no success. I was expecting nothing to be returned and the transaction to go through, so that I could confirm on my end with checking at `http://localhost:5551/api/v1/transactions` - the local mirror endpoint URL.

***EDIT***
Eventually solved, turned out that I needed to scale up my RAM on Docker

---

Comment: Have you updated the reference to [the latest version of @hashgraph/sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hashgraph/sdk) in your package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what fixed it for me was having my .env variables with no strings

So before I had my .env varaiables like so

.env file code

```
MY_ACCOUNT_ID="0.0.5939242"
MY_PRIVATE_KEY="465654654654300706052b.."
```

I was getting a type error so looking at other peoples code I saw they used the
.fromString(..) method from the AccountId & PrivateKey Object, So I added that to my code like so:

index.js code

```
 const myAccountId = AccountId.fromString(process.env.MY_ACCOUNT_ID);
 const myPrivateKey = PrivateKey.fromString(process.env.MY_PRIVATE_KEY);
```

Then I was getting the
throw new Error(`max attempts of ${maxAttempts.toString()} was reached for request with last error being: ${persistentError != null ? persistentError.toString() : ""}`);

So then I removed the "..." from the .env file and the code worked!

Here is [my code repo](https://github.com/Min11Benja/hedera-programmatically-create-account-transfer-hbar)

also make sure your code is in the same line when using object.functions()

The Hedera developer portal has it formated like so but that is WRONG!

```
const newAccount = await new AccountCreateTransaction()
    .setKey(newAccountPublicKey)
    .setInitialBalance(Hbar.fromTinybars(1000))
    .execute(client);
```

Dont use line breaks

```
const newAccount = await new AccountCreateTransaction().setKey(newAccountPublicKey).setInitialBalance(Hbar.fromTinybars(1000)).execute(client);
```